# What is the best way to handle navigation using page object model (java)

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I'm relatively new to page object pattern. What is the best approach for handling header navigation? I don't want have multiple methods for each section or to use enum to store locators. Is this approach makes sense, or there are better options?

This is the code I have using Serenity BDD:

## HeaderNavigationPage

```
public class HeaderNavigation extends PageObject{

@FindBy(xpath = "")
private WebElementFacade  categoryMenu;

@FindBy(xpath = "(//button[contains(@title,'Sign In')])[1]")
private WebElementFacade signInButton;

@FindBy(xpath = "")
private WebElementFacade timeslotButton;

public WebElementFacade getCategoryMenu() {
    return categoryMenu;
}

public WebElementFacade getSignInButton() {
    return signInButton;
}

public WebElementFacade gettimeslotButton() {
    return timeslotButton;
}

public void ClickOnHeaderNavItem(WebElementFacade element){
    boolean elementVisible = element.isVisible();
    if (!elementVisible) {
        element.withTimeoutOf(30, SECONDS).waitUntilVisible();
    }
        element.click();
  }

}
```

## LoginSteps

```
public class LoginInSteps {

private HeaderNavigation  headerNavigation;
private HomePage homePage;
private LoginPage loginPage;

@Step("The user is on login page")
public void OpenLoginPage() {
  homePage.open();
  headerNavigation.ClickOnHeaderNavItem(headerNavigation.getSignInButton());

}
```

Comment: I am also trying to understand what it a common approach when dealing  with multiple locators inside page object.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done that I found worked well is create a class for any sort of reusable element, like your navigation bar and either create it in the constructor of each page that uses it, or better yet - inject it if you are using some sort of factory for your page objects.

I have some C# selenium code like this handy, it should get the point across.

Reusable MenuBar (like your header navigation):

```
public class MenuBar
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public MenuBar(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(//button[contains(@title,'Sign In')])[1]")]
    public IWebElement LogInButton { get; set; }

    public LoginPage ClickLogin()
    {
        LogInButton.Click();

        // Page object chaining, you could use a void return type instead
        return new LoginPage(_driver);
    }
}
```

HomePage constructor:

```
public class HomePage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        MenuBar = new MenuBar(driver);
    }

    public MenuBar MenuBar { get; }
}
```

Used in a test:

```
[Test]
public void TestLogin()
{
    var homePage = new HomePage(Driver);

    var loginPage = homePage.MenuBar.ClickLogin();

    loginPage.Login("username", "password");

    Assert.True(someCondition);
}
```